# Compiler Error (Intel Parallel Studio 2019 with Visual Studio Community 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019, intel-parallel-studio

I have a very simple example

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this with Visual Studio Compiler on Visual Studio Community 2019, then it works as expected.

However, when I change the compiler to Intel C++, installed with Intel Parallel Studio 2019, it returns an error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\utility(92): error : expected an identifier
1>          !_Is_implicitly_default_constructible<_Uty1>::value || !_Is_implicitly_default_constructible<_Uty2>::value)
1>          ^
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\utility(91): error : not a valid member class or function template declaration
1>      constexpr explicit(
1>      ^
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\utility(91): error : "explicit" is not allowed
1>      constexpr explicit(
1>      ^
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\utility(93): error : expected a ";"
1>          pair() noexcept(
1>          ^
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\utility(175): error : expected an identifier
1>      constexpr explicit(!is_convertible<const _Other1&, _Ty1>::value // TRANSITION, VSO#946746
1>                         ^
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\utility(175): error : not a valid member class or function template declaration
1>      constexpr explicit(!is_convertible<const _Other1&, _Ty1>::value // TRANSITION, VSO#946746
1>      ^
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\utility(175): error : "explicit" is not allowed
1>      constexpr explicit(!is_convertible<const _Other1&, _Ty1>::value // TRANSITION, VSO#946746
1>      ^
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\utility(177): error : expected a ";"
1>          pair(const pair<_Other1, _Other2>& _Right) noexcept(is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Ty1, const _Other1&>&&
1>          ^
1>
1>compilation aborted for Source.cpp (code 2)
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I comment out the `#include <iostream>` and `std::cout ~~`, which is basically an empty program, then it compiles successfully and runs without error.

My system is

OS: 64bit Windows 10 Enterprise

CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3970X

Comment: Looks like a C++20 feature that I bet your Intel compiler doesn't support. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20s-conditionally-explicit-constructors/

Comment: check this link to confirm whether your compiler support C++20, [https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-cpp-compiler-release-notes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-cpp-compiler-release-notes),I noticed that 19.0 supports C++17, and 19.1 supports C++ 20

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar compiling erro:

> ```
> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\concepts(47): error : expected ';', near '{'
> ```

If I Disable the "bullseye coverage 8.9.44" (compatible til VS 2015) my prog compile with success.